calculate cmyk, spot coverage on PDF with python
I don't find any free or open source libraries to calculate CMYK and spot color on pdf.
I would be grateful if someone could guide me in the right direction as to what I should do to access color channels and calculate the percentage of color used ( C,M,Y,K and spot, Export each separately ) with Python.
Point: Actually, I don't have a problem with extract C,M,Y,K because I can easily extract it from the image, but the problem is that when I add spot colors, it convert it into cmyk again.
That's why I'm looking for it in PDF.
Thanks

I think I'm offtopic, but I do not understand why in last period we have so many question on CMYK. It seems some people gave a new life on an obsolete colour space. Nobody use it since 30 years. Printers will probably convert it back to RGB (or XYZ, which it is practically the same for this application), apply colour correction and calculate the ink needed. So probably with a lot of dilution of precision because all conversions. I doubt there are any printer which uses directly CMYK. So why so many questions on CMYK?

Giacomo Catenazzi So what is your shampoo label or .. printed with? how gallus, HEIDELBERG and ... work? is about Offset, Flexography printing my friend ;)

Not using CMYK colour space. Shampoo labels usually the client give you the spot colour (as you see in your question), which has much much more information then CMYK can give (or just Pantone colours: but so the printer has the license and he known how to build the colour from the around 20 pantone primary colours. Simple packing? You get the primary you want, you to do print test, and you measure carefully the results and you adapt the output (according the predefined allowed Delta E). At least a 3D LUT. You may use CMYK on offset, etc. but it will converted back before final correction.

Quality printing requires much more than just CMYK (and RGB). And you want to set ink quantities according the printer, not the generic CMYK. And you wrote about shampoo: so possibly some yellow ink, and yellow is tricky on CMYK: yellow inks doesn't fit well on CMYK, so CMYK is no more used for "densidty of ink".

I hope this will be useful for those who have a similar problem in the future.
Dependencies : Ghostscript - Pillow
How does it work ?
Ghostscript will separated colors ( C,M,Y,K, Spots ) and save each one as .tiff and Pillow calculate the percentage of color ( In fact, the file saved by Ghostscript is in grayscale mode and has only one color channel. 0 to 255 ) used on each file.
Point: Before that, make sure you have installed Ghostscript
from PIL import Image
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os , fnmatch

def pdf_color_splitter():

    # Where the photos of separated colors are placed => 
    path = 'image_inputs/'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    
    # now we run ghostscript command for separated colors and save them as tiff files =>
    os.system(f'gs -sDEVICE=tiffsep -o {path}c.tiff  cmyk_calculate/2021.pdf')

    # get all .tiff
    FILES = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), '*.tiff')

    # calculate colors coverage each separately 
    splited_colors = []
    for f in FILES:

        O_FILE = Image.open(path+f)

        image_sizew,image_sizeh = O_FILE.size # get width,height
        count=image_sizeh*image_sizew

        val=0 # Collects colored pixels

        for i in range(0, image_sizew):
            for j in range(1, image_sizeh):
                pixVal = O_FILE.getpixel((i, j))
                if pixVal != 255 and type(pixVal) != tuple: # no white pixels
                val+= 100 - (pixVal//2.55) # Pay attention to the point below this code

        resp = {'name':f.split('.')[0].replace('c(','').replace(')',''),'coverage':val/count}
        split_colors.append(resp)
        os.remove(path+f) # remove .tiff file in the end
        
    return splited_colors

Look to this code
val+= 100 - (pixVal//2.55)

So what was this for?
We want a number in the range of 0 to 100 because we are working in CMYK mode and subtract the answer from 100 because the photo is in Grayscale mode (actually to get the correct color density).

So, you want to dump the raw image channels for images in a PDF. Here is some code to start playing with:
from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfName
from pdfrwx.pdffilter import PdfFilter

count = 0
pdf = PdfReader('file.pdf')
for page in pdf.pages:
    for obj in page.Resources.XObject.values()
        if obj.Subtype != PdfName.Image: continue
        count += 1
        obj = PdfFilter.uncompress(obj)
        print(obj.ColorSpace, obj.BitsPerComponent)
        open(f'dump-{count}.bin', 'wb').write(obj.stream.encode('Latin-1'))

The modules:
pdfrw, pdfrwx (Disclaimer: I am the author of pdfrwx; this module is a work in progress, see module description)
This will print the image's color spaces and dump the raw and partially uncompressed image streams to files. Here, partially uncompressed means uncompressed and given as bytes unless obj.Filter is one of the specific image filters like /DCTDecode (i.e. JPEG), /JPXDecode (i.e. JPEG2000) etc. For multi-component images, e.g. RGB, the raw data that is dumped will be in the form: RGBRGB ..., where each of the R, G & B are obj.BitsPerComponent bits long and all components are contiguous all the way to the end of the row, where they are padded. But if the obj.Filter is one of the image filters you need to remove that filter, so you might want to look at pdfrwx.PdfImage which does that and more: decodes/applies color space etc.; feel free to just grab the necessary part of the code.
